# Why is my Python program throwing an exception depending on the name of the file?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm just learning Python.

I have a file with the following content

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
```

If I name this file `csv2.py` and call:

```
python csv2.py
```

... **it works**. But if I name this file `csv.py` and run:

```
python csv.py
```

It triggers this exception:

```
C:\Git\algotrading [master ≡ +3 ~0 -0 !]> python csv.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "csv.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\andrerpena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 29, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar
  File "C:\Users\andrerpena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py", line 34, in <module>
    import matplotlib.collections as collections
  File "C:\Users\andrerpena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 36, in <module>
    import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
  File "C:\Users\andrerpena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mlab.py", line 172, in <module>
    import csv
  File "C:\Git\algotrading\csv.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'pyplot'
```

It took me like 40 minutes to figure out the problem. I mean.. Figure out the problem had to do with the name of the file.

Why is that happening?

Comment: `csv` is a standard module packaged with Python which `matplotlib` tries to import. Rather than importing the standard module, it's importing *your* file

Comment: `csv` is a standard Python module. Do not call your file `csv.py`, give it another name.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just learning. I didn't know that.

Comment: Python adds the script's path to its module search path and that's why other scripts in the same directory can mask installed modules. You may not have gotten this far yet, but packages that use their own subdirectories don't have this problem. If you make a package `foo`, you can include a `csv.py` in its directory.

Comment: A useful practice is to give your scripts names that contain characters that you won't find in Python modules. For example `my-csv.py` is a perfectly cromulent script name, but it cannot be a module because `import my-csv` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like matplotlib.pyplot through various imports needs mlab.py which calls "import csv". This should find a file (that is not yours) called csv but since you have renamed your file to csv.py it is attempting to import that instead, overriding the required import and messing up the import for matplotlib.pyplot.

Answer (score 2):

`csv.py` is built into python and thus is restricted.

If you run a python interpreter and try to `import csv`, you'll succeed without having to download anything new.

Answer (score 0):

Like **igoldthwaite** and **Daniel Dobalian** said:

If you create a file named: **csv.py** with the content:

```
import csv
print(csv)
```

And run:

```
python csv.py
```

You will see that this file import itself:

```
 <module 'csv' from '/home/your/folder/csv.py'>
```

Also, if you do the same thing with other modules, you will find the same result:

```
import subprocess

print(subprocess)
```

Result:

```
<module 'subprocess' from '/home/your/folder/subprocess.py'>
```

And finally, if you do it with a file named **matplotlib.py**, you will get the same result:

```
import matplotlib
print(matplotlib)
# <module 'matplotlib' from '/home/your/folder/matplotlib.py'>
```